# how to get post from same name textboxes in php

Tags: php, post, textbox, forms

I have a form with multiple textboxes which are created dynamically, now all these textboxes are of same name lets say `txt`, now is there any way that when form processing happens we could read all the text boxes values using `$_POST` method, which are of so called same name. If possible how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to name your textboxes `txt[]` so PHP creates a numerically indexed array for you:

```
<?php
// $_POST['txt'][0] will be your first textbox
// $_POST['txt'][1] will be your second textbox
// etc.    

var_dump( $_POST['txt'] );
// or
foreach ( $_POST['txt'] as $key => $value )
{
  echo 'Textbox #'.htmlentities($key).' has this value: ';
  echo htmlentities($value);
}

?>
```

Otherwise the last textbox' value will overwrite all other values!

You could also create associative arrays:

```
<input type="text" name="txt[numberOne]" />
<input type="text" name="txt[numberTwo]" />
<!-- etc -->
```

But then you have to take care of the names yourself instead of letting PHP doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Create your text box with names txt[]

```
<input type='text' name='txt[]'>
```

And in PHP read them as

```
$alTxt= $_POST['txt'];
$N = count($alTxt);
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      echo($alTxt[$i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want name, you could name the input with `txt[name1]`, then you could get it value from `$_POST['txt']['name1']`. `$_POST['txt']` will be an associative array.