# Save table data into Array?

Tags: php, html, sql, multidimensional-array

I have a table filled with textboxes.
I need to take ALL the textbox values and save them to an array.
I will then convert the array to an string and POST to another page.
I have around 7-8 cloumns, with rows between 1-200
How do I save all this in array?

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php);
mysqli object [2](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php);
while() [3](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php);
mysql_fetch_assoc(4);

Did you even do research yourself?

Comment: The info isn't from MYSQL. It' textbox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990367/how-to-get-post-from-same-name-textboxes-in-php You can do the rest.

Comment: And if it has nothing to do with a database. Remove the SQL tag. Now it is misleading.